# Git revert not working in simple file

Tags: git, version-control

I have one text file and then made `4 commits` adding some stuff

reflog show this

```
b8855f5 HEAD@{0}: commit: sample file 7, 8
76a0a1d HEAD@{1}: commit (amend): sample file 5, 6
c1e92ac HEAD@{2}: commit: sample file 35,6
a96273f HEAD@{3}: commit: sample file 3,4
c296a17 HEAD@{4}: commit: sample file added
```

what i wanted to do was revert the commit `a96273f`

i tried this and got this

```
git revert -n a96273
error: could not revert a96273f... sample file  3,4
hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
hint: with 'git add <paths>' or 'git rm <paths>'
hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'
```

Comment: Have you deleted any of the commited files going from a96273f to the current?

Comment: no, there was only one file , and i am just doing it for test. Its a simple text file with numbers added for tetsing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like `git apply` and `git merge`, `git revert` sometimes needs help from you, the user, to resolve conflicts.

For instance, suppose in commit `a96273` you added the third and fourth lines of the limerick:

```
A mathematician named Klein
Thought the Moebius band was divine
  Said he, "If you glue
  The edges of two
You'll get a weird bottle like mine!"
```

Then, suppose in subsequent commit, you change the spelling of "Moebius" to use an umlaut, "Möbius".

If you then attempt to `git revert a96273`, git sees that the change was to add the two indented lines—which it can find, so that's no problem—but that the line before the first indented line said "Moebius".  The line that is there now does not match.  Git cannot be sure that deleting the two indented lines is correct, so it stops with a conflict, and asks you to edit the file, choose the final correct form, and then do a `git add` and `git commit` to finish the revert operation.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is reset the txt file to a96273, so the command you are looking for is `git reset` not `git revert`.

Try command: `git reset --hard a96273`, this command will discard all the changes after a96273, so it is very dangerous, be careful!

If you only want to scroll back to commit a96273 and don't discard the changes, use `git reset --soft a96273`.

you can check the man page for git-reset